How to write FireSQL queries for Grafana
I have this query in the database called "failsuperapp" but as you can see it is not the default one, so how would I access the data in the collection and perform the query in fireSQL format?
https://i.sstatic.net/oKhz3pA4.png
How to perform a query with fireSQL format for grafana
Please help me I would appreciate it
FireQL: https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/jsayol/firesql/

What is "FireSQL" in this context? Can you provide a link?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.
